# How does exec* functions manage multithreaded process?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, kernel, exec

In POSIX standards, calling `exec*` in a thread will cause the entire process to be replaced with a new process, resulting in termination of all threads of the process.

But how does `exec*` terminate all threads? I searched online for 'how to kill all threads in Python'. But all the answers I got required to have the thread handle first (simply put, I can't kill a thread if I don't have reference to it).

Moreover, different threads of a process can run on different physical cores simultaneously in a multicore CPU. At that time, on one core, if kernel is doing `exec*` what happens to the thread executing on another core at that time? Will it simply try to execute the next instruction, but as it's process image is overwritten by kernel, it will get a SIGILL? In that case, what happens if the thread is handling that signal and not exiting?

On contrary, if the kernel kills all the other threads as a precautionary, and later it finds it can't start new process due to some error (executable not found, etc), then it has to restore the process's original state and return with errno set. How does it recreate killed threads?

Comment: "But how does exec* terminate all threads?" - In the similar way how `kill -9` terminates the process with all its threads. The analogy with Python is simply wrong: In Python you could execute `os.exit(0)` which will kill all your threads (including the current one).

Comment: @Tsyvarev How it kills all threads except current one? Because current thread is still running `exec*`.

Comment: "How it kills all threads except current one?" - Not sure what kind of answer do you expect for that. The kernel is able to control all CPUs, so it is not a problem for it to interrupt running code on every core. If you want a pointer to the code which does this, then such code is quite large.

Answer (score 1):

> how does exec* terminate all threads? I searched online for 'how to kill all threads in Python'. But all the answers I got required to have the thread handle first (simply put, I can't kill a thread if I don't have reference to it).

The OS knows the identities of all of the threads that it manages. If there are any "green" threads—threads that are managed entirely by the program's own code—then those are nothing more than parts of the program state, and they simply will disappear when all the the rest of the program state disappears.

> different threads of a process can run on different physical cores simultaneously in a multicore CPU. At that time, on one core, if kernel is doing exec* what happens to the thread executing on another core at that time?

The thread will be interrupted—same as if it was interrupted at the end of a time slice, except in this case, the interrupt never returns.

> if the kernel kills all the other threads as a precautionary, and later it finds it can't start new process due to some error (executable not found, etc), then it has to restore the process's original state and return with errno set. How does it recreate killed threads?

It doesn't. All of the errors that can be *returned* by `execve` will be detected *before* the OS starts to tear down the old process. But, those don't cover every possible failure case. For other errors, the [man page for `execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) says,

```
in (rare) cases (typically caused by
resource exhaustion), failure may occur past the point of no
return: the original executable image has been torn down, but the
new image could not be completely built.  In such cases, the
kernel kills the process with a SIGSEGV (SIGKILL until Linux
3.17) signal.
```

So, if your program calls `fork()` and `exec()`, You might want the parent process to be prepared for the possibility that the child could unexpectedly terminate. (But if we're talking about an enterprise-grade application, then you already were planning for that, Right? There's more than one reason why a process might suddenly disappear.)